# Copy site collection from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, site-collection, migration

I want to copy a site collection from a SharePoint 2010 farm to SharePoint 2013 farm.

I searched the web, and saw some process, but it seems that something missing.

I tried this article:
http://artykul8.com/2014/10/backup-restore-migration-sp2013/

**What I did is the following:**

- Create a site collection with the same name at sp13 farm.
- Backup site content DB with SQL studio in SP10, and copied it to sp13 db.
- Restore the db with SQL studio at SP13
- On SP13 - run `Test-SPContentDatabase` command (passed OK)
- On SP13 - run `Mount-SPContentDatabase` , I get an **error that DB is already exist**

Comment: skip the first step `create a site collection with the same name at sp13 farm.
`

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Here you need to do the following steps:

To move a site collection from 2010 to 2013 we can go with the approcah of Database detach and attach process;

1. Need to take the backup of the content database in which our site collection resides.
2. Restore this content database to the SQL server of the new SharePoint 2013 environment.
3. Create a new web application in the SharePoint 2013 server under the same port as the existing server and remove the newly created    content database from the web application
4. Run `Test-SPContentDatabase` with our restored content database against this newly created web application, please make sure that it    passes sucessfully without any warnings and errors
5. Run `Mount-SPContentDatabase` to this newly created web application , which will attach our old content database to this    newly created web application and we'll be getting all the site    collections we had in SharePoint 2010 , it upgrades the database if  needed.

Comment: I have web one application, under it there are few Site Collections, every site collection has it own content DB in SQL server. step 3 :I removed the new content DB through Central Admin-> App Management -> Content Data Bases, In the DB I checked "Remove Content Data Base". after I did this action, I can't see the site collection in "View all site Collection" I tried to do this with dismount-SPcontentDB with PowerShell, the same result.